# Cannot view Outlook invitations in Gmail web on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, gmail, google-apps

I have email through Google Apps that I access from my iPhone via the web.  I can view all emails and do everything I need to do except view invites sent from others using Outlook.  I see the message and who it was sent to, but none of the details about the actual time and place.  I can't accept or reject the invite so it never gets added to my web calendar.  Even if I look at my email using the "Desktop" link, it doesn't show the details of the invite.  If I look at it from my laptop, I see the details and can accept the invite and have it show on my calendar.

I do not want to add this account as a mail account on my iPhone, so web access is the best.  Other then not seeing the invite details, I have no other problems.  Is there a way to see those details?

Comment: Just wondering, can you see those details due to some gmail lab addon on the desktop?

Comment: No, I don't have any add-ons on the desktop - I just see the full details when using a computer as opposed to the iPhone. On the iPhone, I only see who it's from and to, but not the time or location nor have the ability to accept the meeting

Comment: When you say "via the web" I'm assuming you mean using Safari? Have you tried using Google Chrome for iOS?

Answer (score 1):

Wallace, to get the full functionality, you should add your google apps as exchange account. Google has provided details for this at the following link:

http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=14252&answer=138740